# JPA native query for "select into outfile"

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am having issue executing a "SELECT INTO outfile" query through JPA native query.

I tried with the following code:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/temp.sql' FROM DummyTable");
return q.getResultList();
```

But I got this exception:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.

Seems like JPA treated it as an update so I changed my code to use execute update:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/temp.sql' FROM DummyTable");
q.executeUpdate();
```

Now, I got another exception.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not
>   execute native bulk manipulation query
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue executeUpdate() for
>   SELECTs

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: You need to treat the query as an update, q.getResultList() will attemp to extract a ResultSet, when you perform a dump ("select into outfile") the result obtained is an integer (or long) indicating how many records were written to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I did try using executeUpdate() but ended up with another exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround.  Using direct JDBC fixed the problem.

```
    Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
    session.doWork(new Work() {

        @Override
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
            try {
                pStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                pStmt.execute();
            } finally {
                if (pStmt != null) {
                    pStmt.close();
                }                       
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[`EntityManager.createQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createQuery(java.lang.String)) creates JPQL query interface whereas [`EntityManager.createNativeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) will create native query interface.

The query which you trying to execute is native one. So, if you change it to createNativeQuery might resolve an issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  I actually did use createNativeQuery but I typed it wrong in the question.  I will fix the question now.